# Use existing neutral wire for ground and switch neutral to ground in breaker panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My garage has an existing receptacle for NEMA 10-50 which has hot-hot-neutral. I plan to install a NEMA 6-50 which requires hot-hot-ground. Can I just use the existing neutral wire as ground at the outlet side AND change neutral in breaker panel to connect to ground bus bar?

Comment: Is your breaker panel a main panel or a subpanel?  Can you post a photo of the inside of the receptacle box, showing the back of the box clearly?

Answer (score 4):

Not quite.  You also need to destroy all the insulation on the neutral-to-be-ground wire which is accessible.

That's a subtle distinction in Code.  You can't convert a hot to a neutral because the wire must be white its entire length.   However, you can convert a hot or neutral to ground, because Code only requires you strip the insulation which is accessible.

### However, don't do that.  Convert to NEMA 14.

NEMA 14 is the "Universal solvent" receptacle that will power whatever went in that 10-50 (hot-hot-neutral) and also anything that takes a 6-50 (hot-hot-ground).

I presume your neutral wire has white insulation because if it was already bare, you wouldn't need to ask about making it a ground.   I am saying *leave it neutral, and add a ground*.

Grounds, unlike any other wire, can be retrofitted.  They can follow a different path back to the panel, they only need to reach anywhere that has a 10 AWG or larger ground path back to the panel, or even a conduit pipe.  Or even the **grounding electrode system**, those copper wires going out to ground rods or water pipes.  (You can't use water pipes, though).